How to make a chart accessible with TalkBack for Android, like iOS's audio graph
Apple's chart's framework has a Voice Over accessibility feature they call an ‘audio graph’ that will play audio tones while the user scrubs their finger across a chart.  Watch at 3:40 in this WWDC demo for what I’m looking to emulate or 2:20 when it plays the whole graph summary.  How can I do the same in Android?
I tried finding similar documentation or third-party libraries, but found nothing.

Create a discussion: How could Android provide a function similar to iOS audio graph

A few question which may make this easier for people to answer: Which chart library are you using? Is this Jetpack compose or views?
